# $\int_{[a,b]}^{} f(z) dz = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{[a_n,b_n]}^{} f(z)dz $

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence, complex-integration

I have two sequences $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ on $\mathbb{C}$ that converge to $a$ and $b$ respectively. I have an open set $U$ on $\mathbb{C}$ which has the segment $[a,b]$ inside, and $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ a continous function. I need to prove that $$\int_{[a,b]}^{} f(z) dz = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{[a_n,b_n]}^{} f(z)dz .$$ 
I know that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{[a_n,b_n]}^{} f(z)dz = \lim_{n\to\infty} (b_n - a_n) \int_{0}^{1} f(a_n + t(b_n - a_n)) dt$$
so i just need to prove that the function sequence $f(a_n + t(b_n - a_n))$ converges to $f(a + t(b - a))$ (uniform convergence), can you please help me proving that that function sequence converges(uniform convergence)? Thank you

Comment: I think you just need to use that a continuous function on a compact domain is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Also, notice that $|[a_n + t(b_n - a_n)] - [a + t (b - a)]| \le (1 + t)|a - a_n| + |b - b_n| \le 2|a-a_n| + |b - b_n|$ uniformly in $t \in [0,1]$.